# Phonegap(cordova 3.5) Android Build failed

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-3, command-line-interface

I am working on cordova 3.5 project in Mac. I have created and build using CLI. But Android build failed. I have set sdk path. Below is the error I am getting. I have not added any plugin.

```
cordova build android

Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
Preparing android project
Compiling app on platform "android" via command "/Users/user/Documents/Phonegap_Projects/Test1/platforms/android/cordova/build" 
Error: An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant debug -f "/Users/user/Documents/Phonegap_Projects/Test1/platforms/android/build.xml"": 
BUILD FAILED
/Users/user/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/user/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/user/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Class not found: javac1.8

Total time: 2 seconds


at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/compile.js:65:22)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:969:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the java compiler is not in your PATH.  Take a look at the [PhoneGap Android Platform Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide).

> You may also need to enable Java and Ant. Open a command prompt and
>   type java, and also type ant. Append to the PATH whichever of these
>   fails to run:
>
> ```
> ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin
> ```

You can test your configuration by running `javac` at a command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you answer suitable for windows system. I am working on Mac

Comment: Same steps apply on unix/linux. On windows you edit %PATH% via dialog. On a mac, you edit ~/.bash_profile, adding a line PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME\bin:$PATH:$ANT_HOME\bin
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

Comment: Of course, the JAVA_HOME variable should already be be defined.